# printing one number to one row in print

Tags: awk

How to print one number to one row? I don't now how to use \n with function.

```
/^$/{flag=""} /Input-Output in F Format/{flag=1;next} flag && ($0 ~ /^[0-9]/ ||
$0 ~ /^ [0-9]+/) && ($0 !~ /26      0/ && $0 !~ /28      0/){ print t($5) t($6)} function t(n,  s) { s=index(n,"."); return (s ? substr(n,1,s+6) : n) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
print t($5) "\n" t($6)
```

In awk, space is concatenate.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot " "